# Why might this abnormal xml behaviour be happening

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

There's a function that I have written which basically does encryption for me 4 times in a day and writes the encryption in a xml file. Now we have 4 regions them being Dev,QA,ITE and PROD. I did not get any errors in DEV,QA,ITE but in PROD weird things are happening.
The first exception on which the code failed was this

`Invalid XML document, The document does not have a root element..   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)`

and got this exception too:

```
The process cannot access the file 'configfile.xml' because it is being used by another process.   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, StringmaybeFullPath)at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share) at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(String filename)
```

I have a feeling this is happening due to concurrent requests. The programming language used is C# with ASP.NET 2.0.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Can you post a code sample of how you're working with the file?

Comment: Sorry mate cannot post code. Strict rules

Comment: could you maybe recreate the problem in a separate project that doesn't contain company code and can use dummy names, as long as your problem is visible?

Comment: I'll do that and update this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "file being used by another process" exception is certainly down to trying concurrent access (and this could be from the current process).

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653) can help here: search for the name of the file to see what processes have handles to the file.

With respect to the XML error: either XML is "Well Formed" or it isn't XML. And that means having exactly a single root element.

Well formed:

```
<root>
  Stuff
</root>
```

Not XML:

```
<root1>
  Stuff
</root>
More stuff
```

There is limited capability within .NET for loading "XML Fragments" which can break the document rules, but this is really for insertion into a complete document, *not* as an alternative to the XML rules.